# CakePHP2 file upload plugin

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I use paperclip plugin for Ruby on Rails app.
What is the defacto standard file upload plugin like paperclip for CakePHP2?

https://github.com/davidpersson/media supports only CakePHP1.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default plugin defined, a suggestion would be to use the Uppy Plugin with ajax request, for more information go to:

```
[1]: https://uppy.io/docs/plugins/
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

David Persson's Media Plugin doesn't have a 2.0 compatible release, but somebody [forked it](https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin) to make it run on newer versions of Cake. This fork is actively developed (which also means things might still be broken) and with no official release incumbent it seems the best option to run the Media Plugin.

Apart from Persson's plugin there's [MeioUpload](https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload) which is also widely used and seems to be compatible with Cake 2.0.

There's [Uploader](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader) (currently at version 3.3), which is compatible with Cake 2.0 (probably 2.1 as well).

Lastly, [the plugin FileUpload](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin/tree/cakephp2.0) by WebTechnick (known for his Facebook plugin for Cake) has a 2.0 branch which hasn't seen an official release, so proceed with caution.